# colorButtonNormal works correctly on my 4.3 android device

Tags: android, android-version

I am new in android. According to a note:

> colorButtonNormal will only work on phones running API 22 and above.
> So if you have an older phone, the buttons will not be colored orange.

My Android version is 4.3 (API 18) , but they change to orange without problem!

- so why this happened?
- does it mean that my android version has a high API?

  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your project includes **support-v7-appcompat**, it supports the `colorButtonNormal` attribute. That should be the reason why.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.attr.html#colorButtonNormal

Comment: I have imported this: **android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;**
do you mean that?

Comment: @SINA Yes, that is one of the v7 appcompat library. cf. https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat

Comment: you are right, but what do you think about android version? does v7 appcompat work for all APIs? because the note said it only work for API 22. But my version is 18.

Comment: @SINA The appcompat library is for backward compatibility. Some of, but not all of, newer APIs are usable on the older android vesion devices.